# Graphically showing composition and inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, applet, composition, graphic

I have a Java assignment and I need to graphically show composition and inheritance. I have it done showing multilevel inheritance but not graphically. This can be done in two ways.

**Method 1**: Is to demonstrate multi-level inheritance. (This is what I have done) 
For example: a Eagle is-a Bird and a Bird is-an Animal

**Method 2**: Is to pass one or more parameters to the SUPERCLASS. 
This requires that the information is first passed to the subclass constructor.
Then the information needs to be redirected to the superclass constructor with the super keyword.
It also requires that this information is used by the superclass in a meaningful fashion.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

  class Plane extends Applet {
    public Plane()
    {
        System.out.println("Class Plane");
    }
    public void vehicleType()
    {
        System.out.println("aircraft Type: Plane");
    }
}
class Boeing extends Plane{
    public Boeing()
    {
        System.out.println("Class Boeing");
    }
    public void brand()
    {
        System.out.println("Brand: boeing");
    }
    public void speed()
    {
        System.out.println("Max: 593 mph");
    }
}
public class Boeing787 extends Boeing{

     public Boeing787()
     {
         System.out.println("Boeing Type: 787");
     }
     public void speed()
        {
            System.out.println("Max: 593mph");
        }
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         Boeing787 obj=new Boeing787();
         obj.vehicleType();
         obj.brand();
         obj.speed();
     }

}
```

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: try using `fields` to store the data in e.g. `protected String vehicleType;` then this field should be *set* from the constructor and retrieved using the `vehicleType` method

Comment: Graphically show the code i posted or one of the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass parameters to the superclass you'll first need a constructor that has formal parameters in the parent class.  For example, all vehicles have a length, width, and height, so you might create a constructor in a class, vehicle, that takes three formal parameters: length, width, and height.  A plane is a type of vehicle but also has another characteristic specific to an instance of a plane: max altitude.  You'll need a constructor for an instance of a plane that sets the instance variables of the parent (length, width, and height) but also max altitude.

```
public Plane(double l, double w, double h, double max)      
{
    super(l, w, h);
    maxAltitude = max;
}
```